# Fc_Chartupdated Is Not Called at Hlinear Guage Update

Tags: fusioncharts, gauge

I am trying to display and update HLINEAR GAUGE fusionGadget pointer value. When I am dragging the pointer , the function FC_ChartUpdated is not being called. I have tried using RealtimeUpdateComplete eventListener too. But it displays error 'Object does not support property / method 'setAttribute''..Can you please tell me the reason?

We have to call that JS function or It will be called automatically when Gauge is updated?

Here is my code,

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>FusionGadgets</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>      
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
   <div id="chartdiv" align="center">FusionGadgets</div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        var myChart = new FusionCharts("HLinearGauge.swf", "myChartId", "450", "120", "0", "0");
        myChart.setDataURL("Data.xml");
        myChart.render("chartdiv");
   </script> 

</body>
<script>

FusionCharts("myChartId").addEventListener("RealtimeUpdateComplete" , myChartListener);
function myChartListener(){
 alert('Hi.');
}

  function FC_Rendered(DOMId)
        {  //alert(Math.round(pointerValue));    
         //Check if DOMId is that of the chart we want
                if (DOMId=="myChartId"){
                //Get reference to the chart
                var chartRef = FusionCharts(DOMId);
                //Get the current value
                var pointerValue = chartRef.getData(1); 
                //You can also use getDataForId method as commented below, to get the pointer value.
                //var pointerValue = chartRef.getDataForId("CS"); 
                //Update display
                  alert(Math.round(pointerValue));    
                             }

        }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,After had been working for several hours,this issue has been resolved.These are the steps which made the issue was resolved...

1.passing registerWithJs value '**1**'.

var myChart1 = new FusionCharts("HLinearGauge.swf", "myChartId1", "450", "105", "0", "**1**");
2.Changed Flash Player Global Security Settings..
    [for more info](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Tools/FlashPlayerSecuritySetup/HowToSetup.html)
3. Chang the FusionCharts.js file to new version.

4.After had made these changes,I encountered with new issue, 
  chartRef.getData(1) gives javascript error (Object does not support the property/method).
  So then I changed the code for getting chart reference 
  to
    **var chartRef = getChartFromId(DOMId);** 
  from
    *var chartRef = FusionCharts(DOMId);*